# Create instance of a class in the definition of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want translate this Java code into Python.

```java
public class word {
    public int s
    public Word(int t){
        s = t
    }
    public static final Word a = new Word(2)
}
```

I tried this code:

```py
class Word:
    a= None

    def __init__(self,t):
        self.s= t
        if not Word.a:
            Word.a= self.__init__(2)
```

which I got from chatgpt, but it can't run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can just put `Word.a = Word(2)` after your class definition.

Answer (score -1):

This is the same isn't it?

```
class Word:
    a = None

    def __init__(self, t):
        self.s = t

Word.a = Word(2)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it can't run.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\玩\as-pseudocode\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Word:
  File "d:\玩\as-pseudocode\a.py", line 8, in Word
    a = Word(2)
NameError: name 'Word' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ord'?

Comment: it runs in my environment, exactly like that (refresh the page maybe I did edit the answer)

Comment: with that code then `print(wordobject.s)` prints 2

Comment: I need the instance in side of defination of class, anyway, this questions are be solved, thanks for you answer

Comment: yes I see, I updated so that `a` acts as the static field